# How to add new buttons to JqueryTe (texteditor plugin)

Tags: jquery, textarea

How do I add custom buttons to **JqueryTe** editor plugin:

```
add button: <center>string</center>
add button: add image url <img src="string" />
```

[code.google.com/](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryte/)

[jqueryte.com](http://jqueryte.com)

Comment: Hi Erfan, maybe you could ask [plugin's author](http://jqueryte.com/about) directly for this nice addition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the plugin has initialized, you can do..

```
var newButton = $('<a class="myButton" unselectable="on" />');
$('#someContainer .jqte_Panel').append(newButton);

newButton.on('click', function(){
 //new functionality
});
```